# Optimizing Solr for Sorting

Tags: lucene, solr

I'm using Solr for a realtime search index. My dataset is about 60M large documents. Instead of sorting by relevance, I need to sort by time. Currently I'm using the sort flag in the query to sort by time. This works fine for specific searches, but when searches return large numbers of results, Solr has to take all of the resulting documents and sort them by time before returning. This is slow, and there has to be a better way.

What is the better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer.

If you want to sort by time, and not relevance, use fq= instead of q= for all of your filters. This way, Solr doesn't waste time figuring out the weighted value of the documents matching q=. It turns out that Solr was spending too much time weighting, not sorting.

Additionally, you can speed sorting up by pre-warming your sort fields in the newSearcher and firstSearcher event listeners in solrconfig.xml. This will ensure that sorts are done via cache.

Answer (score 2):

Obvious first question: what's type of your time field? If it's string, then sorting is obviously very slow. `tdate` is even faster than `date`.

Another point: do you have enough memory for Solr? If it starts swapping, then performance is immediately awful.

And third one: if you have older Lucene, then `date` is just string, which is very slow.

Comment: I've got Solr on a dedicated box with 30GB of RAM allocated. That said, a query for "show me all items, page 1, 100 rows per page" will swap (I assume) when Solr tries sorting by date, since my index is about 120GB. I think this is the root of my problem. I am using Solr 1.4.1, the latest, which I assume comes with the latest Lucene. I am using date. Maybe tdate will speed things up?

Comment: Solr 1.4.1 uses tdate for date fields, but with a precision step of 0. I bumped it up to a precision step of 4 (the recommended default), but I'm not seeing a speed increase. I think the problem is just swapping when running giant datasets.

Answer (score 1):

***Warning***:  Wild suggestion, not based on prior experience or known facts.  :)

1. Perform a query without sorting and rows=0 to get the number of matches. Disable faceting etc. to improve performance - we only need the total number of matches.
2. Based on the number of matches from Step #1, the distribution of your data and the count/offset of the results that you need, fire another query which sorts by date and also adds a filter on the date, like `fq=date:[NOW()-xDAY TO *]` where `x` is the estimated time period in days during which we will find the required number of matching documents.
3. If the number of results from Step #2 is less than what you need, then relax the filter a bit and fire another query.

---

For starters, you can use the following to estimate `x`:

If you are uniformly adding `n` documents a day to the index of size `N` documents and a specific query matched `d` documents in Step #1, then to get the top `r` results you can use `x = (N*r*1.2)/(d*n)`. If you have to relax your filter too often in Step #3, then slowly increase the value 1.2 in the formula as required.

Comment: This might actually work. The penalty for performing the search twice will probably add about 200ms to the request, but it might be worth it to avoid sorting huge datasets. I'll try this out. I think there must be a better way though.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that this looks a bit flaky. Another option (the warning in my answer still applies) may be to maintain more than one index - one with data for last week, another with data for last month, another for last year etc. (Choose the time periods based on your requirements and data/query distribution). When you get a new query, fire it on the smallest index and check if you get the required number of results. If not, fire it on successively larger index till you get the required number of results.